# ionic3 - InAppBrowser plugin not working

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

First install `InAppBrowser` plugin

> $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
>
> $ npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser

After that import to project.

`.ts` file:

```
  launch(url){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      cordova.iab.open(url, "_blank", "location=no");
    });
  }
```

`.html` file:

```
<button (click)="launch('https://ionicframework.com/')" style="width:30%" ion-button color="danger" >TEST Button</button>
```

And when I run in IOS device, xcode show nothing in log page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, problem solved.

`.ts` file

```
  launch(url:string){
    this.InAppBrowser.create('https://ionicframework.com/',"_blank","location=no");
  }
```

`.html` file

```
<button (click)="launch(url)" style="width:30%" ion-button color="danger" >TEST Button</button>
```

Comment: Its not working me.. If I add it into provider, app is getting crash.. but removed from provider, app is showing error for null pointer provider for inappbrowser.

Comment: @androidOnHigh Why add it into provider? Try add it into page site and if still got error tell me here.

Comment: @androidOnHigh Could you show me the error and also show me your code.